# How do i change this for loop into a dictionary/list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying a few different ways but i cant seem to wrap my head around dictionary comprehensions and i could really use some help.

```py
if count == 1: 
        for player in game: 
            game[player]['Points'] = 0
```

Comment: You are not compelled to use dict comprehension. It is there for the reason that it is readable. In your case there are multiple statements. I would say, keep it the way it is.

Comment: game = {k: {'Points' : 0} for player in game}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I disagree with Vishnudev and think that written as a comprehension the code is just as simple. Here's a solution to your previous complex code. I wrote the comprehension by writing the right side of the comprehension first and then adding code on the left side in the comprehension.

```
import random


def gameStarts(game, count):
    print(f"Game summary for Game {count}")
    return {
        throw: [random.randrange(1, 7) for _ in range(4)]
        for throw in ["throw1", "throw2"]
        for player in game
    }


game = {"alice": {}, "bob": {}}
print(gameStarts(game, 0))
```